# FATAL EXCEPTION, Runtimeerror in doInBackground() method of async task

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, runtimeexception

I'm getting a FATAL EXCEPTION, Runtimeerror in doInBackground() method of async task.

The situation is: i have a ChatActivity and within this i'm using RESTFUL Client call to server for updating my groups.
i got 4 async tasks in that activity and 3 of them (delete, add, load) are working like a charm, but the other one won't.

I found some posts with same errors but

- i don't have some uihandling in my background method and
- there is no NPE anywhere in logcat,

so i tried anything i could imagine whould cause this error, but no success...

here'S the log
(sorry for the external link, but got no 10 points for images :/ )
http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ik6wet&s=8#.U7h94nV_vZs

my code is on github

[Link to Github Repository](https://github.com/marcelh89/DAS-SYSTEM-APP/blob/master/src/com/example/das_system_app/activities/ChatOrganizeActivity.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have an infinite loop in asyncTask. Check the method doInBackground to see if is generating loop

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try to use a service for that, but i don't understand why the other async tasks are working and this one is producing loop.